# Electrical insulation resistance of TO-220 package with SIL pad and plastic shoulder washer?

Tags: heatsink, insulation, to220, hipot

**What would a ballpark insulation voltage (HI-POT) rating be for a TO-220 package (with a "hot" tab) mounted to a grounded heat-sink with SIL pad and shoulder washer?**

I am not seeing much documentation about this. I want to replace a TO-220 "FP" insulated package with a non-insulated package + SIL pad + shoulder washer if possible.

I found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237329678_How_to_Keep_Your_Cool_While_Working_With_Power_Electronics_Static_Thermal_Design_Issues), and at the bottom of the tenth page it reads, "The breakdown voltage [of a SIL pad] is 3500-4500 Vac". It references a Bergquist brand Sil-Pad® 400 product datasheet.

Perhaps the electrical insulation resistance of the *pad itself* is 4 kV, but I highly doubt the *whole assembly* would be rated for that. When compressed, even if grease were used to fill the voids around the screw, and it is kept meticulously clean.

The TO-220 device in question is a 16 A, 1200 V rated SCR, being supplied half-wave 408 V AC (~600 V DC pulses).

Comment: To increase rating on the assembly you can use an aluminum oxide insulator and TO-247 package.

Comment: Just a note, on an unrelated repair unit I have finally seen one SIL pad with a hole in it, where arcing had occurred *through* the pad.  Must've been either a defect in the pad, physical contaminant during assembly, and/or one very strong over-voltage event.  Rare, but it can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP400-.007" is good for upto 5kV Hipot.

[image]

[Farnell Ref](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/99609.pdf)